# Terraform: How to use variables for the value of AWS ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, firewall

I have code as follows:

```
data "aws_arn" "stateful-rulegroup" {
  arn =  "arn:aws:network-firewall:${var.region}:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup"
}
```

```
 24     stateful_rule_group_reference {
 25       priority     = 21
 26       #resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:${var.region}:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"
 27       resource_arn = join("/", [data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup, "AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"])
 28     }
```

Line 26 works. But line 27 fails. I got errors as follows. How to make a variable for resource_arn, like resource_arn = var.resource_arn?

```
│   on fw_policy.tf line 27, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_firewall_policy" "anfw_policy":
│   27:       resource_arn = join("/", [data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup, "AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling join(separator, lists...)
│     │ data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup is object with 7 attributes
│
│ Invalid value for "lists" parameter: element 0: string required.
```

Comment: Just pass the string directly to resource_arn instead of going through the data source. The data source really only makes sense if you an arn to begin with and want to extract data from it - and even then it is debatable if it is useful because the arn is well defined and you can just string split on any colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint for the issue is mentioned in the error message, `data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup is object with 7 attributes`.

When you use `data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup` you are actually using the entire object instead of its one attribute however, [join](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/join) function produces a string by concatenating all of the elements of the specified *list of strings* with the specified separator.

In order to get single attribute , specifically `arn` as this is intended `data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup.arn` should be used in `join` function.

### Terraform code for reference

```
variable "region" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) describe your variable"
  default     = "eu-central-1"
}

data "aws_arn" "stateful-rulegroup" {
  arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:${var.region}:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup"
}

locals {
  ## Correction is Here ## 
  resource_arn = join("/", [data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup.arn, "AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"])
}

output "resource_arn" {
  value = local.resource_arn
}
```

### Plan/Output

```bash
data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup: Reading...
data.aws_arn.stateful-rulegroup: Read complete after 0s [id=arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-central-1:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup]

Changes to Outputs:
  + resource_arn = "arn:aws:network-firewall:eu-central-1:aws-managed:stateful-rulegroup/AbusedLegitBotNetCommandAndControlDomainsStrictOrder"
```

Hope this helps :)